# Proof that $ |\sin{1/t} - \sin{(t + 1/t)}| \leq |t|$ for $0 < |t| \leq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How one can proof that for $0 < |t| \leq 1$ we have that
$$ |\sin{1/t} - \sin{(t + 1/t)}| \leq |t|. $$

I've been think in a way to approach this problem, however I dind't get anywhere.
Help?

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Using $$\sin(a)-\sin(b)=2\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right),$$
and $$|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$$ for all $x$ allow you to conclude.